# How often should the /info route be accessed?

Tags: support

The `/sites` method makes it very clear that you should not invoke that route more than once per day:

> "It is suggested that you cache its return for at least one day..."

However, the `/info` method contains the text:

> "This data is cached very aggressively, by design. Query sparingly."

How often is too often? Should I assume that one request per 24 hours is the maximum (like the `/sites` method)? Currently my PHP library caches the data for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No more than once an hour is a decent guideline.

I'll update the documentation to suggest this.

Comment: P.S. I see the documentation got a facelift - I like it!